# iOS - UI Label Not Updating

Tags: swift, alamofire, weather-api

I am trying to build a weather app with AlamoFire and i am getting the JSON Response as expected but when i am trying to update the date to UI Label, my variable is returning a nil. if anyone get a chance to let me know where i am going wrong

```
import UIKit

class WeatherVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLbl: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var weatherType: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityname: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentTemp: UILabel!

    var  weatherConstants = WeatherConstant()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       // updateUI()
//
        weatherConstants.downloadCurrentWeather {

self.updateUI()

        }

        weatherConstants = WeatherConstant()
        print(Current_Weather_Url)


    }


    func updateUI() {

            weatherType.text = weatherConstants.weatherType
            cityname.text = weatherConstants.cityName


        print("current city name is \(weatherConstants.weatherType)")
    }



}
```

Weather Constants

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire


class WeatherConstant {
    var  _cityName :String!
    var _currentTemp : Double!
    var _weatherType : String!
    var _highTemp : String!
    var _date :String!




    var cityName :String {
        if _cityName == nil {
            _cityName = ""
        }
        return _cityName
    }

    var currentTemp : Double{

    if _currentTemp == nil {
    _currentTemp = 0.0
        }
        return _currentTemp

    }

    var weatherType : String {
        if _weatherType == nil {
            _weatherType = ""
        }
        return _weatherType
    }
    var highTemp : String {
        if _highTemp == nil {
        _highTemp = ""
    }
        return _highTemp
}

    var date : String {
        if _date == nil {
            _date = ""
        }
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none

        let currentDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())

        self._date = "Today, \(currentDate)"
        return _date
}
    //func downloadWeatherDetails(completed : DownloadComplete) ===> downloadWeatherDetails(completed : @escaping DownloadComplete)


    func downloadCurrentWeather(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
        Alamofire.request(Current_Weather_Url).responseJSON{ response in

            let result = response.result
           // print(result)
              debugPrint(result)

            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                if let name = dict["name"] as? String {
                    self._cityName = name
                    print("current name is \(self._cityName)")
                }

                if let currentTemp = dict["weather"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                    if let main = currentTemp[0]["main"] as? String{
                        self._weatherType = main
                        print("Current Weather Type \(self._weatherType)")

                    }
                }

            }
            completed()

        }

    }




}
```

JSON Response

```
https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=e9a34088739f38c517b4a45084f5ed82
SUCCESS: {
    base = stations;
    clouds =     {
        all = 0;
    };
    cod = 200;
    coord =     {
        lat = "35.02";
        lon = "139.01";
    };
    dt = 1485792967;
    id = 1907296;
    main =     {
        "grnd_level" = "1013.75";
        humidity = 100;
        pressure = "1013.75";
        "sea_level" = "1023.22";
        temp = "285.514";
        "temp_max" = "285.514";
        "temp_min" = "285.514";
    };
    name = Tawarano;
    sys =     {
        country = JP;
        message = "0.0025";
        sunrise = 1485726240;
        sunset = 1485763863;
    };
    weather =     (
                {
            description = "clear sky";
            icon = 01n;
            id = 800;
            main = Clear;
        }
    );
    wind =     {
        deg = 311;
        speed = "5.52";
    };
}
```

Current Weather Type Optional("Clear")----> this the weather type i am trying to provide to UIlabel

current city name is Optional("") ------> Here i am trying to print what data is in UILabel but its returning empty string

2018-08-07 11:18:09.567868-0700 WeatherApp1.1[82321:3248301] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2881 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert

Comment: You should update the UI on main thread. 

Try this :    weatherConstants.downloadCurrentWeather {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateUI()
            }
        }

Comment: Horrible code. This is not Objective-C. Don't use backing private variables with leading underscores to get constants. In Swift declare for example `cityName` as `let cityName : String` and delete the entire `var cityName :String {...}` expression. And write an initializer. Openweathermap sends very reliable data.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the `weatherConstants` value with a new object in `viewDidLoad`. Try removing that.

(Longer explanation: you're correctly creating a `weatherConstants` object, and asking it to fetch data. But while that's happening, you create a second instance of that object which overwrites the first. So while the first instance completes the network request and tells your UI to redraw, the UI is getting its data from the *second* instance of `WeatherConstants`)